# Getting error with dpkg

Tags: server, dpkg, 14.10

I recently upgrade my 14.04 server to 14.10 and I got this error message during the upgrade:

```
Setting up sysv-rc (2.88dsf-41ubuntu18) ...
info: Reordering boot system, log to /var/lib/insserv/run-20141030T2142.log
error: Something failed while migrating.

error: Unable to migrate to dependency based boot sequencing.

See http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot for
more information about dependency based boot sequencing. To
reattempt the migration process run 'dpkg --configure sysv-rc'.

dpkg: error processing package sysv-rc (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Whenever I install packages/use dpkg I get a very similar error. This never happened on 14.04.

**EDIT:** Added below is a log that might contain more information

```
info: Converting rc0.d/S* and rc6.d/S* to K*.
ls: cannot access S*: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access S*: No such file or directory
info: running insserv
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service bind9 and apache2 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service apache2 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service bind9 at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service sendsigs at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
```

Comment: so what happens when you run "dpkg --configure sysv-rc" as advised ?

Comment: same errror message show up

Comment: It is a bug and you have not posted enough information for me to give you an answer. There is a discussion here - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145964/ubuntu-trusty-preseed-error but I did not see a fix

Comment: i've included the latest log in my post

Comment: remove apache and bind 9 and try again. Then re-install apache and bind 9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, but in my case it was caused by the `virtuoso-nepomuk` script.

Instead of removing `bind9` and `apache`, I would suggest just moving their scripts out of the `/etc/init.d` directory.  That should allow the process to complete, then you can do an `apt-get install --reinstall ...` on those packages after you're done updating to get their startup reconfigured properly.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have errors in your configuration files for bind9 and wide-dhcpv6-client. If you have not manually edited those yourself (ie you are using/want to use the default DHCP/DNS client behavior), you should issue

```
apt-get install --reinstall bind9 wide-dhcpv6-client
```

and when it asks you if you wish to keep your current configuration files, tell it to overwrite yours with the package maintainer's version.

I had this issue after using do-release-upgrade to go from Trusty to Xenial. I guess somewhere in there it didn't quite upgrade from Upstart to systemd properly. Anyway, the above fixed the issue for me.

If apt is reporting errors in your config files for the DHCP server, you probably want to correctly resolve that anyway. 3vi1's answer just kind of pushed the possible issue under the rug to trick apt into doing what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Doing this on a Dell Precision M3800 laptop shipping with Ubuntu, I had to do the same for `/etc/init.d/dell*`.